# Django : find encrypted password in the database with filter

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

when I register a new user, his password is encrypted in the database with the sha1 method.
When I want to search if a user is or not already register in the database for my login page, I have to check if the email address exist and then if the password which is send is the good.
This is my code :
*views.py :"

```
#Login
@api_view(['POST', ])
def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {}
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        password = hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf-8'))
        account = memberArea.objects.filter(email = email, password = password)
        if account.exists():
            for account in account:
                data['succes'] = "Successfully connected"
                data['id'] = account.id
                data['email'] = account.email
        else : 
            data['error'] = "email and password doesn't match !"
        return Response(data)
```

Here, I try to encrypt the password which is send by the user and then to search into the databse for this encrypt password.
After testing it doesn't work.
Thank's by advance for helping me.

Comment: DO NOT STORE ENCRYPTED PASSWORDS IN A DATABASE! Please read some articles on how to appropriately handle passwords with an unique salt and irreversible hash. Anything less leaves you inappropriately susceptible to having your users' passwords stolen in a data breach.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things to unpack here.

1. You should never write your own password hashing method. You can be sure it's all there. A small mistake can cost you a lot.
2. You should absolutely not filter with password. If you want to check if password is matching, then
3. For setting password, `User` model has `set_password` and for checking if it's correct there's `check_password`

You didn't show how you register a user, but if your user model uses `AbstractBaseUser` then that's probably what you need to do.

Also, there's this `authenticate` function that does it all based on how you configured your backends in settings.

You can find it there
`from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`

Comment: Thanks. I think so I have to remake my register api

Comment: If you want a simple configurable REST API for login/register, there's https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser that I can recommend. (disclaimer, I work for a company that developed this). Tutorial can be found here. https://sunscrapers.com/blog/django-rest-framework-login-and-authentication/